# How to set the 'android:exported' property to "true" in the 'AndroidManifest.xml' file in Unity

Tags: android, xml, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

Whenever I try to upload my Unity project to the Play Console, it gives me the following error:

'You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported' (SEE IMAGE BELOW)
[image]

So, I did some research and tried to implement the 'android:exported' property to my AndroidManifest.xml file. The first thing I did was to create a Plugins map, which I further subdivided with an 'Android' map. After that I went to 'Player Settings > Publishing settings', and checked the box 'Build Custom Main manifest', so that a AndroidManifest.xml file would be placed in Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml, so I went back to my project and got the following result:
[image]

So I opened the script and added the line `android:exported="true". Anyway here's the script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Name of the script:

[image]

BUILD SETTINGS:

[image]

Mergded Manifests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.DefaultCompany.com.unity.template.mobile2D"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.vulkan.version"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="unity.build-id"
                android:value="com.DefaultCompany.com.unity.template.mobile2D" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.notch_support"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity> <!-- Add this section for External Dependency Manager -->
        <provider
            android:name="com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.PurchaseUpdatesetInitiator"
            android:authorities="com.DefaultCompany.com.unity.template.mobile2D.com.unity.purchasing.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/com_unity_purchasing_path" />

            <grant-uri-permission
                android:pathPattern="/purchase_update.*"
                android:pathPrefix="/purchase_update" />
        </provider> <!-- End of section -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window"
            android:value="False" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="notch.config"
            android:value="portrait|landscape" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.build-id"
            android:value="87f3da67-806f-4324-b8ac-8ddbda0eb6ed" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationManager"
            android:exported="true" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So what is the question? If you have the same error after your changes in the custom manifest, there can be several reasons. First of all, there can be several activities in your result manifest. You can check it using AndroidStudio by loading your APK/AAB there. You will be able to see the result manifest with all activities and flags in it.

Comment: Also, it will be useful to know what Unity version and what build settings are you using.

Comment: I am using Unity 2020.3.24. So my question is: How can I change the script, so that the Google Play Console will know that `android:exported="true", and I edited the post an put an image of the build settings in there, so you can see it.

Comment: And what is in the resulting manifest? As I've said above, you can check it in AndroidStudio.

Comment: I added the merged manifest in the original post.

Comment: So, according to the error you got from the google play store, check all activities and broadcast receivers in the result manifest. As far as I see, there last one has no needed property. You can either try to update needed package, that adds this part to the manifest or export android project instead of build, open it in the AndroidStudio, make changes manually and build project there.

Answer (score 0):

To set the 'android: exported' property to "true" in the 'AndroidManifest.xml' file in Unity, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your Unity project and navigate to the Assets/Plugins/Android folder.
2. Create a new file named 'AndroidManifest.xml' in this folder if it does not already exist.
3. Open the 'AndroidManifest.xml' file in a text editor or Unity's built-in text editor.
4. Add the following code inside the 'application' element:

   ```
    <activity
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">
   </activity>
   ```

This will set the 'android: exported' property to "true" for the main Unity activity.

5. Save the file and rebuild your Android project in Unity.

Note: Setting 'android: exported' to "true" can make your app vulnerable to security issues if not used properly, so make sure to understand the implications and use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the following steps

1. goto `Assets/Plugin/Android` folder
2. find and open AndroidManifest.xml
3. set true by default it is false

> android:exported="true"

4. Save the changes
5. Rebuild